# Do HTML WebSockets maintain an open connection for each client? Does this scale?

Tags: html, websocket

I am curious if anyone has any information about the scalability of HTML WebSockets. For everything I've read it appears that every client will maintain an open line of communication with the server. I'm just wondering how that scales and how many open WebSocket connections a server can handle. Maybe leaving those connections open isn't a problem in reality, but it feels like it is.

Comment: There is no such thing as an HTML WebSocket. You mean HTTP WebSocket.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

In most ways WebSockets will probably scale better than AJAX/HTML requests. However, that doesn't mean WebSockets is a replacement for all uses of AJAX/HTML.

Each TCP connection in itself consumes very little in terms server resources. Often setting up the connection can be expensive but maintaining an idle connection it is almost free. The first limitation that is usually encountered is the maximum number of file descriptors (sockets consume file descriptors) that can be open simultaneously. This often defaults to 1024 but can easily be configured higher.

Ever tried configuring a web server to support tens of thousands of simultaneous AJAX clients? Change those clients into WebSockets clients and it just might be feasible.

HTTP connections, while they don't create open files or consume port numbers for a long period, are more expensive in just about every other way:

- Each HTTP connection carries a lot of baggage that isn't used most of the time: cookies,  content type, conetent length, user-agent, server id, date, last-modified, etc. Once a WebSockets connection is established, only the data required by the application needs to be sent back and forth.
- Typically, HTTP servers are configured to log the start and completion of every HTTP request taking up disk and CPU time. It will become standard to log the start and completion of WebSockets data, but while the WebSockets connection doing duplex transfer there won't be any additional logging overhead (except by the application/service if it is designed to do so).
- Typically, interactive applications that use AJAX either continuously poll or use some sort of long-poll mechanism. WebSockets is a much cleaner (and lower resource) way of doing a more event'd model where the server and client notify each other when they have something to report over the existing connection.
- Most of the popular web servers in production have a pool of processes (or threads) for handling HTTP requests. As pressure increases the size of the pool will be increased because each process/thread handles one HTTP request at a time. Each additional process/thread uses more memory and creating new processes/threads is quite a bit more expensive than creating new socket connections (which those process/threads still have to do). Most of the popular WebSockets server frameworks are going the event'd route which tends to scale and perform better.

The primary benefit of WebSockets will be lower latency connections for interactive web applications. It will scale better and consume less server resources than HTTP AJAX/long-poll (assuming the application/server is designed properly), but IMO lower latency is the primary benefit of WebSockets because it will enable new classes of web applications that are not possible with the current overhead and latency of AJAX/long-poll.

Once the WebSockets standard becomes more finalized and has broader support, it will make sense to use it for most new interactive web applications that need to communicate frequently with the server. For existing interactive web applications it will really depend on how well the current AJAX/long-poll model is working. The effort to convert will be non-trivial so in many cases the cost just won't be worth the benefit.

**Update**:

Useful link: [600k concurrent websocket connections on AWS using Node.js](http://www.jayway.com/2015/04/13/600k-concurrent-websocket-connections-on-aws-using-node-js/)

Comment: I still don't know how to scale once you hit the wall, though. It's true that WebSockets consume fewer resources (they scale vertically),  but HTTP is great for scaling horizontally. I can theoretically add servers to scale infinitely. I've always been confused about how to scale once you use up a single box's capacity. Thoughts?

Comment: @Sean. WebSockets isn't necessarily worse at scaling horizontally. It just opens up new applications that don't necessarily scale as easily. For example, for serving static data, a bunch of WebSocket servers would scale just as well (or better) than a bunch of HTTP servers. A low-latency real-time game is hard to scale regardless of the transport (and it's just not really feasible using HTTP). The real question is how well you data/application scales. If that scales, then your choice of HTTP vs WebSockets should be based on other factors: latency, deployment options, browser support, etc.

Comment: One correction - a TCP connection consists of destination ip & destination port. That means that ±64k ports limit is actually ONLY for a single client. Theoretically, the server can have any number of open connections, limited ONLY by its hardware.

Comment: @Rizon, that's true. I've updated the answer and changed the open port limitation and instead mentioned the file descriptor limitation which is the one that people often run into first.

Comment: About your points: 1. HTTP is over IP, which is a packet protocol: saving the headers won't make your communication faster. 2. Logging is to be tuned, and is usually disabled for RESTful requests in favor to application level logs. 3. Websocket is only slightly cleaner than long pooling, and has also to handle keepalives. 4. Event-Driven HTTP servers are the standard now, one connection = one thread is deprecated. 5. Latency is highly physiological, tied to subjectivity. You can have responsive web apps without websockets. 6. WebSockets have big potential security issues (e.g. DOS)...

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez 1. Websocket and HTTP use IP (specifically, TCP/IP). HTTP sends headers for every request (Websockets sends them just once to set up the channel). Those take up bytes and must be generated by the client and processed by the server for every HTTP request. 2. Most HTTP servers default to having at least some level of logging for every request. Yes, it can be tuned to be less. 3. WebSockets requires only a few lines of code on client and server. Robust long-polling often requires hundreds of lines of code to implement correctly. If IE ever adopts SSE that will certainly help.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez 4. Event driven web servers are certainly much more common than 3 years ago when I originally wrote that. However, I expect the majority of web traffic is still served by thread-pool style web servers. 5. Latency is subjective but measurable. Plain HTTP will never reach round trip latency of WebSockets. SPDY/HTTP2 adopt principles from WebSockets in order to bring down round trip latency. Long-poll HTTP/SSE can approach WebSockets for server->client latency but not roundtrip. 6. Regarding security, see this: http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/02/28/html5-websocket-security-is-strong/

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez this addresses many of the same points: http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/08/06/html5-websockets-identified-as-security-risk-really/

Comment: @kanaka 1. More or less. IP transmission means that some headers bytes won't make a difference, since they will be transmitted within the same packet. 2. Agree. This is the best practice I wrote about. 3. Both WebSockets and long-polling require libraries, to be honnest. 4. I expect event-driven HTTP server be the majority today. 5. Agree. But IMHO HTTP2 (if extended) may replace websockets, which is a workaround technology. 6. Your link about security is a child joke (DOS/MIM?). See http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-12/Briefings/Shekyan/BH_US_12_Shekyan_Toukharian_Hacking_Websocket_Slides.pdf

Comment: I wrote a blog article - see http://blog.synopse.info/post/2014/08/16/Will-WebSockets-replace-HTTP-Do-they-scale - which extend my answer below.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez 1. Typical HTTP headers exceed standard packet MTU. 5. WebSockets is a workaround, but HTTP2 won't/doesn't aim to replace it.  That blackhat article is dated (2 years old, just after the standard). Their conclusion is that WebSockets has approximately the same security issues as HTTP (which I should point out was basically the goal of the IETF working group). And they conclude that WebSockets should be used for: time critical data delivery, true bidirectional flow, interactivity, higher throughput. Not just "a protocol to push notifications from the server to the client."

Comment: About security we surely do not have the same experiment. I used to work in the army and for casinos, and I still have doubts. See http://security.stackexchange.com/q/48378 which states that avoiding DOS attacks would require additional server process, so would not help scaling. WebSockets are not worth it. They do not scale safely, while simple requests over CDN are, especially with mobile apps which tend to be the biggest growning part of the Internet. See http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=11974#p11974

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez "These days it's near impossible to thwart a traffic based DoS without some kind of hefty physical firewall in the network." That is true for all network services. WebSockets is not unique in that respect. For delivering static content, CDN is an excellent option. WebSockets were not designed with server->client static content delivery in mind. The sweet spot for WebSockets is for interactive applications, especially ones that need low latency client->server communication (and/or low-latency roundtrip).

Answer (score 38):

Just a clarification: the number of client connections that a server can support has nothing to do with ports in this scenario, since the server is [typically] only listening for WS/WSS connections on one single port.  I think what the other commenters meant to refer to were file descriptors.  You can set the maximum number of file descriptors quite high, but then you have to watch out for socket buffer sizes adding up for each open TCP/IP socket.  Here's some additional info: https://serverfault.com/questions/48717/practical-maximum-open-file-descriptors-ulimit-n-for-a-high-volume-system

As for decreased latency via WS vs. HTTP, it's true since there's no more parsing of HTTP headers beyond the initial WS handshake.  Plus, as more and more packets are successfully sent, the TCP congestion window widens, effectively reducing the RTT.

Comment: AFAIR there is one incoming port, but always one outgoing port opened for each connection. This is in deed only one part of [the C10k problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem).

Answer (score 17):

Any modern single server is able to server [thousands of clients at once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem). Its HTTP server software has just to be is Event-Driven (IOCP) oriented (we are not in the old Apache one connection = one thread/process equation any more). Even the HTTP server built in Windows (http.sys) is IOCP oriented and very efficient (running in kernel mode). From this point of view, there won't be a lot of difference at scaling between WebSockets and regular HTTP connection. One TCP/IP connection uses a little resource (much less than a thread), and modern OS are optimized for handling a lot of concurrent connections: WebSockets and HTTP are just OSI 7 application layer protocols, inheriting from this TCP/IP specifications.

But, from experiment, I've seen two main problems with WebSockets:

1. They do not support CDN;
2. They have potential security issues.

> So I would recommend the following, for any project:
>
> - Use WebSockets for client notifications only (with a fallback mechanism to long-polling - there are plenty of libraries around);
> - Use RESTful / JSON for all other data, using a CDN or proxies for cache.

In practice, full WebSockets applications do not scale well. Just use WebSockets for what they were designed to: push notifications from the server to the client.

About the potential problems of using WebSockets:

*1. Consider using a CDN*

Today (almost 4 years later), web scaling involves using [Content Delivery Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (CDN) front ends, not only for static content (html,css,js) but also [your (JSON) application data](https://cdnify.com/blog/cdn-for-apps).

Of course, you won't put all your data on your CDN cache, but in practice, a lot of common content won't change often. I suspect that 80% of your REST resources may be cached... Even a *one minute* (or 30 seconds) CDN expiration timeout may be enough to give your central server a new live, and enhance the application responsiveness a lot, since CDN can be geographically tuned...

To my knowledge, there is no WebSockets support in CDN yet, and I suspect it would never be. WebSockets are statefull, whereas HTTP is stateless, so is much easily cached. In fact, to make WebSockets CDN-friendly, you may need to switch to a stateless RESTful approach... which would not be WebSockets any more.

*2. Security issues*

WebSockets have potential security issues, especially about DOS attacks. For illustration about new security vulnerabilities , see [this set of slides](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-12/Briefings/Shekyan/BH_US_12_Shekyan_Toukharian_Hacking_Websocket_Slides.pdf) and [this webkit ticket](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32246).

WebSockets avoid any chance of packet inspection at OSI 7 application layer level, which comes to be pretty standard nowadays, in any business security. In fact, WebSockets makes the transmission obfuscated, so may be a major breach of security leak.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez - +1 for the nice exposition on CDN. Quick follow up question - what do you think of the feasibility of Event delivery networks? Patterned after CDNs but geared toward delivering streaming data etc over websockets or some other as yet unseen technology.

Comment: I think you are very right. The cdn point is very valid. Today is very common to use CDNs or cache to scale easily. WEBsockets make this type of scalation difficult. So it is a very important point to take into account

Answer (score 8):

Think of it this way: what is cheaper, keeping an open connection, or opening a new connection for every request (with the negotiation overhead of doing so, remember it's TCP.)

Of course it depends on the application, but for long-term realtime connections (e.g. an AJAX chat) it's far better to keep the connection open.

The max number of connections will be capped by the max number of free ports for the sockets.

Comment: You can keep the connection open without using a WebSocket (thanks to the keep alive option of HTTP/1.1). I'm not sure I understand your point here.

Comment: +1. People tend to forget setting up a TCP connection involves a syn/ack/ack and TLS requires more round trips for the key exchange.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection#HTTP_1.1 WebSockets are open as long as you want and are not hackish (like long-polling and other alternatives).

Answer (score -4):

No it does not scale, gives tremendous work to intermediate routes switches. Then on the server side the page faults (you have to keep all those descriptors) are reaching high values, and the time to bring a resource into the work area increases. These are mostly JAVA written servers and it might be faster to hold on those gazilions of sockets then to destroy/create one.
When you run such a server on a machine any other process can't move anymore.