# refresh div with ajax and callbacks

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a div that loads a counter for things such as how many posts .etc, I want this to update automatically. Currently I am using:

```
function count() {
    $('#refresh-me').load('stats_counter.php?table=projects');
}
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    count()
}, <?php echo _REFRESH_INTERVAL; ?>);
count();
```

Users can add/publish events, and I want this counter to update. I think I need to trigger a callback everytime the user publishes or adds events to update this counter. I am aware things such as http://amplifyjs.com/ exist, but I am wondering what is the most intuitive and "easy" way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, polling is the easiest way, not always the best way.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107384/server-scalability-html-5-websockets-vs-comet